# How to create a chart that compare numeric values to a specific field in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So i have this chart that was filled by users with data that . Now I want to compare some fields with others in order to create graphs. For example, I want to compare the age of each entries with their level in english.

example:
[image]
Let's say i want to have the age on the x-axis and the level on the y-axis, how do i proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that data is in a tab called Sheet1 in columns A and B.
In a new tab put this formula in cell A1 to get the data into a graphable dataset:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"select A,COUNT(A) where B<>'' group by A pivot B",1)
```

Then, select those columns and choose Insert>Chart and choose a type of chart (probably "Bar"?)

(Note: Some syntax would be different in some European countries.)